# Laravel SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known

Tags: laravel

Before this project, I could not get this type of error. But at this time, I faced it.

```
composer require laravel/ui
php artisan ui:auth
```

**.env**

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=katherine_cleaners
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

After this,

```
php artisan migrate
```

**Error**

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.  (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = katherine_cleaners and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

  at F:\katherine\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:678
```

I tried following `php artisan` command: `config:clear`, `cache:clear`, `key:generate`. Also, I change the database name on MySQL and .env. And even, I deleted this project and create a new one. But this doesn't help me.

**Does anyone know, how to figure out this error?**

Answer (score 3):

Your host in .env should be pointing to the IP of your database. Assuming your database is residing on the same server as your Laravel application, it should be:

```
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
```